# How to GoBack to the previous Activity ? Kotlin ( using a button outside the action bar)

Tags: android, android-studio, button, kotlin, back

Using a Kotlin code i want to know how to add a button outside the action bar which takes me to the previous Activity on click

Comment: just call finish()

Comment: thank you very much it's working ^_^

Comment: is there any way to reload the content of a WebPage on Button Click

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call finish() when button is clicked

```
button.setOnClickListener {
   finish()
}
```

Comment: is there any way to reload the content of a WebPage on Button Click

Comment: You can call webview.loadUrl(url) or webview.reload()

Answer (score 6):

Just call `onBackPressed();` method from whereever you want to go back to the previous activity/screen. as follows :

```
btn.setOnClickListener(){
  onBackPressed()
}
```

Comment: is there any way to reload the content of a WebPage on Button Click

Comment: try to set the webclient again on the button click

Comment: what you mean exactly can you give me a code please